# Extracting text and retaining formatting

Tags: c#, itext

Is there an option to extract text from a PDF doc, with the ITextSharp library, and retain formatting eg. the new line and tab characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the formatting "`\r\n`" is indeed retained verified by fetching the value from SQL Server table programatically and invoking `Console.writeline()`. Initially I was copying the value directly from SQL Server Management studio and pasting into text file - which surely isn't the right way to verify.

Answer (score 2):

When extracting text the tab characters will come out, assuming that they actually are tab characters. I don't believe that new line characters can be determined without manually keeping track of the current text coordinates. <strike>You *might* be able to count the number of `Td` tokens between `BT` and `ET` and subtract 1 but that's just a guess.</strike>

**EDIT**

Never mind on the token thing, I thought that was used only for line readjustment (new line) but I was wrong.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Consider I have a StringBuilder object called buffer and I invoke buffer.AppendLine(strategy.GetResultantText() );, it fetches text without formatting/metadata such as  paragraphs etc. On the other hand If I declare a StreamWriter object, named writer, and invoke  writer.WriteLine(strategy.GetResultantText()); ,into a text file, formatting is preserved  e.g. paragraphs. Now Question is, is there a way to use the  StringBuilder object to build a string that retains the formatting - paragraphs etc - from the extracted PDF document? Ultimately I'll be storing the string as varchar

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you write your own `TextExtractionStrategy` based on `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`.

You'll need to track where the baselines are to determine newlines.

Actually, LocationTextExtractionStrategy just might add the newlines for you.  Either way, that's where you need to start.